Explicit undefined properties after Angular migration
We recently migrated multiple Angular 16 projects into a single NX mono repo using Angular 17.
Everything works fine, BUT there is a strange behavior on our models. before the migration, properties that were no set were just no shown at all... while now, they are explicitly set as "undefined". And this can sometimes create problems while calling HTTP API as they interpret this "undefined" as a value...
Ex before migration

Example after migration

I'm thinking about a change in typescript, such as
{
   "compilerOptions": {
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true
    }
}

But all values are set to false... (and it's a compilation settings)
My question is.. what could have caused this change in behavior?
Edit : I managed to reproduce the new behavior on the same mono repo but with Angular 16. So it's not related to Angular 17. But it still could be a new version of typescript, or a new global configuration.. I just don't know which one.

What do you mean by "not shown at all"?
If you're just looking at it in your IDE, and it's not actually causing different behavior, then I suspect that it's an artifact of the IDE itself, since properties that are not set would indeed be undefined in practice, and, for instance, shouldn't appear when json-serialized.
I think that this is probably a non-problem.

These captures are from Firefox. And yes, the behavior is different, because when the object is sent as a body in a HTTPRequest, all undefinedp properties are sent as "undefined". Before, they were no sent at all, and we didn't have any custom code to filter that.
I just want to find a global solution (and if possible, the real cause of the change), instead of fixing all http calls.

@ALansmanne try checking the ES2022 change in tsconfig.json, try reverting to previous and checking

That's it !
Es2016 -> No undefined properties
Es20222 -> All properties always shown

Changing the
"target": "es2022",

to
"target": "es2016",

reverts back to the old behavior.
Now, I still think we should handle undefined values properly so we'll stick to ES2022.
It also seems that the actual change is related to
"useDefineForClassFields": false,

I've found some topics this was set to false by Angular... but changing it to true/false, even when keeping ES2022, will either change or revert the behavior with undefined class properties.
